# Is there a way to set a certain property for all controls in a form at once in the Designer?

Tags: c#, winforms, properties, designer, anchorpoint

I want to set a certain property (`Anchor`) of all the controls in my main form at once.
There are around 100 controls and I really don't want to change this property for each single control manually.

I know I can select all available controls at once by typing `Ctrl + A`. The problem then occuring is that the desired property I want to change is not visible in the Properties window. And normally it should be visible because all the controls are a type of `Control`, shouldn't it?

I also know that I could do it like this:

```
foreach(Control ctrl in myForm.Controls)
{
   ctrl.Anchor = AnchorStyle.Bottom;
}
```

But I want to know if thers's a way of doing this using the Designer. Is there any?

Comment: What is *strg + A*? You mean Ctrl-A?

Comment: I've had to do similar things (with the Font property) and found the simplest way was to edit the .Designer.cs file directly and copy/paste the desired value

Comment: @Jazimov German keyboard, sorry for that...

Comment: Ah! Now I know for future reference--thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Usually if controls derive from the same base, you can select them all at once (using the mouse click and drag or holding down ctrl or shift while selecting them one by one), and then you can set any property that they all share from the base class.

Comment: `if controls derive from the same base`that is very important indeed. Otherwise the property will not appear even if all selected controls have this property, shame on you microsoft

Answer (score 1):

You can multi-select all controls on the form and see the Anchor property in the Property Grid. When you edit that with multiple controls selected, each selected control will be set to the Anchor value you specify.

But be careful with Ctrl-A--it will select visual controls as well as non-visual components. So if you have any components on your form that don't render in the client area of the form (such as the Timer or FolderBrowserDialog form components), the Ctrl-A will continue to show common properties--but because these components don't have an Anchor property, the Anchor property won't appear. The only properties to appear when multiple controls on a form are selected are those share by all selected controls.